# Flask session data works in localhost test, but not working in the main server

Tags: flask, flask-login, localserver, flask-session, flask-cors

I have a small login form for the flask website that receive the login info from `<form>` tag in html with post method and validate the user, afterward the user_id will store in session to check in `@app.before_request` if session contains user_id or not.
The code works fine when testing in the locallost and by 1 time login I can see different pages.
But on the main server, after I log in, it navigates to the first page and by refreshing or navigating to the other page session will remove and goes to login page again.

would you please help me what is the reason and what would be the way to solve it?

Login page post method:

```
session['user_id'] = user[0][0]
session['user_name'] = user[0][1]
session.modified = True
return redirect('Dashboard')
```

other page check method:

```
if 'user_id' in session:
   return render_template('Report1.html')
return redirect('Login')
```

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    session.permanent = True
    g.user_id = None
    g.user_name = "You are not logged in"
    if 'user_id' in session:
        g.user_id = session['user_id']
        g.user_name = session['user_name']
```

Answer (score 1):

For the app secret_key I used `os.urandom(...)`, but I changed it to a fixed string and solved it!